# does movl affect upper bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, mov

A homework question I don't understand the answer to:

> Assuming all registers start at 0, what is the value of the RBX registers at the end of this assembly code?

```
mov $31, %bl
sal $32, %rbx
movl $32, %ebx
sar $31, %rbx
```

I predicted that the answer would be 62, by assuming that `movl $32, %ebx` should only affect the lower 32 bits. However, when I run this code in SASM, it seems that `movl` also zeros-out the upper 32 bits, and the answer is 0. Is this expected behavior? Is this a bug in SASM? Why does `movl` affect the upper 32 bits?

Comment: SASM doesn't emulate the instructions, it single-steps them on your actual CPU.  You can usually trust what a debugger shows you.  (bugs in a debugger are *possible* but typically only affect how information is displayed in the UI, not corrupting the architectural state.  But this is not a bug, it's good ISA design.)

Comment: Thanks (genuinely), whoever marked this as duplicate. I couldn't for the life of me find the answer via web search. No idea why.

Comment: No worries. That Q&A has been one of the more useful canonical duplicate targets to point people at.  Apparently not all x86-64 intros/tutorials cover this critical point.  (And BTW, I didn't know that SO hides the close voters from low-rep users, but apparently it does.)